# Unable to login, old site with previous developer gone

Tags: admin, login

I hope someone can help, one of my colleagues has a church website which used to be managed by one of the church-goers. However, the person who setup the website has since passed away. Unfortunately, he did not leave any details on how to manage the website.

We have access to the admin login panel, I have tried the usual logins of admin, password etc etc. But have had no luck. I have limited experience with using WordPress so I do not know if it is possible to gain access to this website. It would be very helpful, as we need to update mass times and other details on the website.

Is there anyway to gain access to this admin panel without the username or password?

If anyone could help it would be very appreciated,

Thanks,

David

Comment: share with me more detail @David

Comment: You can login to the phpmyadmin and reset the password for admin https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_phpMyAdmin

Comment: you can access database tables through cpanel as well

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I don't have the admin email, unfortunately I think the person who setup the site did not set the email to one that the church uses. How would I know if I have access to phpMyAdmin?

Comment: You can browser the users table, visit https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_phpMyAdmin and you'll get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you can reset

1. if you remember email address ( admin email ) you can simply click on forgot password and enter there relevant email address and there you'll get reset link.
2. If you have database access like phpmyadmin follow steps below:

   - login to phpmyadmin
   - find your site's database. ( e.g., wp_dbname )
   - find the table row named wp_users, click on it
   - then you will need to choose the username you want to change the password for
   - click on edit, there you will see user_login and user_pass fields
   - enter new user name and password ( in case of password field, you will see numbers, ignore them and delete all the letters from there and then enter your desired password. remember the letters are case sensitive ) and Select MD5 from dropdown for password field.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ftp access to the site, do the following:

1. Create folder `/wp-content/mu-plugins` if it does not exist.
2. Create file with any name, lat say `add-admin.php` in this folder.
3. Put the following content to the file.

File content:

```
<?php
function add_admin() {
    $login    = 'new-admin-name';
    $password = 'any-password';
    $email    = 'your-email@domain.com';

    if ( ! username_exists( $login ) && ! email_exists( $email ) ) {
        $user_id = wp_create_user( $login, $password, $email );
        wp_update_user( array(
            'ID'   => $user_id,
            'role' => 'administrator',
        ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_admin' );
```

Then open login page `your-site.org/admin` and Log in with the credentials specified in the code above in `$login` and `$password`.

Upon successful login, you can delete this file `add-admin.php` - you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Although @maverick's answer is basically correct, it is incomplete.

Note that when you enter a plain text password when editing that admin user record, you have to select "MD5" also for that field. Just entering plain text password won't work.

You can also just change the email for the admin account, then do the 'lost password' thing.

Once you get admin control, then create a new admin user for yourself, log in as that user, then delete (or demote) the current admin user. Look are the users list and 'prune' as needed.

You might also consider (recommended) changing the password for the database, and FTP/hosting users to block the 'old' admin. And use 'strong' passwords for all.

And back up everything: databases and customized code.

Comment: Oh I noticed that just now. Yes It'll never work if we don't select MD5 for that field.
Thank you for correction